# Conditions for which all orbits are periodic through varying constants.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

**Question:** Consider the following autonomous vector ﬁeld on the plane:
$$\dot x = ax+by$$
$$\dot y = cx+dy $$
$$(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \qquad (a, b, c, d)  \in \mathbb{R}$$

$\bullet$ Give a set of conditions on $a, b, c, d$ for which the vector ﬁeld has no periodic orbits.

$\bullet$ Give a set of conditions on $a, b, c, d$ for which all of the orbits are periodic.

$\bullet$ Using $V(x,y)= \frac{1}{2}(x^2 +y^2)$ as a Lyapunov function, give conditions on $a, b, c, d$ for which $(x,y) = (0,0)$ is asymptotically stable.

$\bullet$ Give conditions on $a, b, c, d$ for which $x = 0$ is the stable manifold of $(x,y) = (0,0)$ and $y = 0$ is the unstable manifold of $(x,y) = (0,0)$.

**Answers:**

$\bullet$ By the Bendixson criterion I can take $\dot x = f(x,y)$ and $\dot y = g(x,y)$ and find that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = a + d$ so for $a +d \neq 0$ the vector field has no periodic orbits.

$\bullet$ Using the Lyapunov function at the point $(x,y)=(0,0)$, I have that $V(0,0) = 0$ and $V(x,y) \gt 0$ for any neighborhood around the origin, thus it is Lyapunov stable.

We have: $\dot V(x,y) = \frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\dot x + \frac{\partial V}{\partial y}\dot y$

$=x(ax+by) + y(cx+dy)$

$=ax^2+dy^2+(b+c)xy \lt 0$ for asymptotical stability.

Hence for the vector field to be asymptotically stable, we must have $a, d \lt 0$ and $b + c = 0$

$\bullet$ We have a linear system: 
$$\begin{pmatrix}  \dot x \\ \dot y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix}$$

So we can analyse the stability through the matrix of the form $\dot x = Ax$ with $A= \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ is the Jacobian at $(0,0)$

For $a \le 0, x = 0$ is the stable manifold, and for $d \gt 0, y = 0 $ is the unstable manifold. The sign and magnitude of $b,c $ does not affect the stability, thus $(b,c) \in \mathbb R $ is valid.

These are my answers so far, however I am unsure of what conditions I could give for $a,b,c,d$ for all possible orbits to be periodic. I would also very much appreciate if anyone can point out any errors or incorrect statements in my answers.

Comment: Regarding the first and the second question: the system is linear homogeneous, and the phase portrait is perfectly known depending on the eigenvalues (see e.g. Chapter 2 in Devaney, Hirsch and Smale [Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and an Introduction to Chaos](https://www.amazon.com/Differential-Equations-Dynamical-Systems-Introduction/dp/0123820103)). The Bendixson criterion is a very blunt tool here.

Comment: Regarding the third question: No "must" here: that is only a sufficient condition.

Comment: Regarding the fourth question: the necessary and sufficient condition is that $(0,1)$ be an eigenvector with a negative eigenvalue and $(1,0)$ be an eigenvector with a positive eigenvalue.  What does the matrix $A$ look like now?

Comment: @user539887 Thank you for your responses, you've just reminded me that for all solutions to be periodic we need to have $a, d = 0$ and $b = -c$ to have the eigenvalues of this matrix be the purely imaginary numbers $\pm ib$ for the solutions to form a centre, and I can see just choose the constants to have the matrix be of a canonical form ie a sink with $a \lt d \lt 0 $

Comment: @user539887 For your reply to the fourth answer, I can see that my previous answer was slightly off, and to get a negative eigenvalue for $(0,1)$ and positive eigenvalue for $(1,0)$ I simply need the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & d \end{pmatrix}$ with $a \gt 0$ and $d \lt 0$

Comment: For the eigenvalues of the matrix to be purely imaginary we do not need its diagonal entries to be zero: $\begin{pmatrix}-1&2\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @user539887 looking back on this, surely the eigenvalue for the stable manifold must be negative and positive for the unstable manifold? I believe my answer for the fourth one in the first place was correct and that I just need $a \lt 0$ and $d \gt 0$ with $b, c$ chosen that the eigenvalues are still negative and positive respectively.

Comment: No, it is not enough: the axis $x=0$ must be the stable and $y=0$ the unstable manifold, so their spanning vectors must be eigenvectors.